# Does Bisq have built-in wallet support for anything other than Bitcoin and BSQ?

Tags: bisq

I've long wondered about this but been unable to find any answers.

In theory, one could use Bisq and not even have Bitcoin Core, or at least I believe such is the case. You could use it as your sole Bitcoin wallet, with local private keys and all. (But in practice, I don't trust it as much as I trust Bitcoin Core, so I transfer it out to my Bitcoin Core wallet.)

It also supports its own cryptocurrency, called "BSQ". That much I know for a fact, and it makes sense.

But what about all the other garbagecoins that it supports for trading? Does it actually allow you to hold those inside Bisq, with no extra software having to be installed? For example, if I buy an Ethereum (not that I would), can Bisq hold that or would it require me to have a separate "Ethereum wallet" installed to transfer to?

Are Bitcoin and BSQ just "special cases", or are any crypto currency that Bisq supports for trading actually supported within Bisq itself to hold and manage?

Answer (score 1):

> In theory, one could use Bisq and not even have Bitcoin Core, or at least I believe such is the case.

You can use use your Bitcoin Core node with Bisq: https://bisq.wiki/Connecting_to_your_own_Bitcoin_node

> But what about all the other garbagecoins that it supports for trading? Does it actually allow you to hold those inside Bisq, with no extra software having to be installed?

No. The seed in Bisq can only be used for BTC and BSQ. BSQ is stored in a Bitcoin wallet, but the Bisq software takes several measures to keep BSQ and BTC separate to prevent mixing the two by accident. On disk, BTC and BSQ wallets are stored in separate files.

> are any crypto currency that Bisq supports for trading actually supported within Bisq itself to hold and manage?

**Altcoins are a type of** [**payment account**](https://bisq.wiki/Payment_methods). Every offer on Bisq designates a payment method for traders to settle payments. **The Bisq software does not actually integrate with any payment methods—all non-bitcoin fund transfers are made outside of Bisq software.**

Some altcoins have specific requirements. [Monero](https://bisq.wiki/Trading_Monero), for example, requires that sellers be able to provide a transaction key in case of a dispute, which is not available in all XMR wallets. L-BTC buyers must use a wallet that shows the blinding key